# CSWP Find Unassigned Tasks

Tags: 2013

I'm working on figuring out the CSWP and trying to come up with a query which will allow me to return a list of all of the Tasks in our Site Collection which have not been assigned to someone to work.

So far I figured out how to query for my own Tasks and Tasks of other specific users, but not how to find any tasks which have not been assigned.

I've tried using the following filters:
`AssignedToOWSUSER=""`
`AssignedToOWSUSER:""`
`AssignedTo=""`
`AssignedTo:""`

The queries I have tried all return 0 results when I know there are many unassigned tasks in our Site Collection and subsites.

I'm sure this is probably something simple, but I have not found any good examples of how to filter based on empty/blank/null values.